# Is it possible to combine annotations together with attributes in PHP 8.0

Tags: symfony5, php-8

Is it possible to combine annotations together with attributes like:

```
    /**
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     */
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime')]
    private ?DateTime $createdAt;
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? The language itself isn't going to stop you, so it's a question of what a specific tool is going to read. I think more details are needed before anyone can give you a useful answer.

Comment: My question is if the PHP docblock is ignored when php 8.0 attributes are used

Comment: I get that, but my question in response is _ignored by what_? Neither docblock annotations nor attributes do anything unless something _actively reads_ them, so different libraries might or might not read both.

Comment: In this case it’s an example of using annotations and attributes to declare doctrine (ORM) fields.

Comment: So, the question is, does _Doctrine ORM_ support _reading_ both annotations and attributes in the same project? That can probably be discovered by looking at their documentation (or, for that matter, by testing it with some existing code).

Comment: I’ve tested and it seems working just needed confirmation ☺️

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes: at least some declarations (eg. routing, security and Doctrine) work side by side in different formats. So there is no hard rule preventing this.

I'm not sure however if there aren't some edge cases where this could backfire, and if you can you should try to keep to one format. There's Rector tool that can handle converting those automatically. In my experience it's sometimes hard to find a proper rule for Rector but there is a nice playground (https://getrector.com/demo) and good support on GitHub.

Comment: Rector combine annotations with attributes